# FFMPEG Image2pipe Producing Broken Video

Tags: video, ffmpeg, pipe, image2pipe

I'm trying to write a program that pipes PNG data into FFMPEG to render it into a video. The program's video output wasn't working so I am using PNG screenshots as debug input.

The screenshots are all valid PNG files that open normally in any image viewer. However when I run the command:

```
cat 2017*.png | ./ffmpeg -f image2pipe -r 1 -vcodec png -i - -vcodec libx264 out.mp4
```

I do get a video output that has 1 second of video for each screenshot starting with 2017 in the directory. However, the video is entirely black and finishes **instantly** after starting to play the video. (Not one second or frame for each frame).

This is on MSYS on Windows, using a Windows version of FFMPEG, if it makes any difference.

What can I change so it will actually make a video out of the piped input? My first guess is that it might have something to do with either incorrect args or a lack of an appropriate codec.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

```
cat 2017*.png | ./ffmpeg -f image2pipe -framerate 1 -i - -c:v libx264 -vf format=yuv420p -r 25 -movflags +faststart out.mp4
```

- Use the `-framerate` input option instead of `-r` for image2pipe demuxer.
- Many players have trouble with such low frame rate MP4. Add the `-r` output option to give it a more normal output rate. `ffmpeg` will duplicate frames to match but it will still look as if it is 1 fps.
- Add `-vf format=yuv420p` (or the alias `-pix_fmt yuv420p`) to make the output use a widely compatible pixel format.
- Use `-movflags +faststart` to enable faster starting playback.

Comment: How to extend the video to specific duration?